# How to deactivate kernel modules "firewire_ohci" and "firewire_core"?

Tags: 12.10, kernel, lubuntu, firewire

My computer currently uses the kernel modules `firewire_ohci` and `firewire_core`. I don't want them.

I blacklisted them, but they still load after any reboot. How can I deactivate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you rebuild:

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u && sudo reboot
```

If that doesn't work you should be able to disable them in GRUB.